# Bootstrap form-groups in well wrong spacing

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I use form-groups in a well element, but
the **bottom visible margin is more than the top**, and this is not looking good. I want it to be centrelised vertically.

[image: <code>enter image description here</code>]

```
<div class="well">
<div class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group">
    ....
    <div class="form-group">
    ....
</div>
</div>
```

**Snippet**

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="well">

  <div id="date_formatter_widget">

    <!-- Widget -->

    <div class="form-horizontal">

      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-9 text-right">
          <input type="text" class="form-control conversionPattern" id="pattern" placeholder="pattern here...">
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
          <input type="text" class="form-control conversionPattern" id="conversionPattern" placeholder="" readonly value="2015-05-21">
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

    <!-- /Widget -->

  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: It's about because of well's "padding", I think.

Comment: Okay, that doesn't look good alright. What's your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.form-group`'s last child has a `margin-bottom`, which can be removed by setting this:

```
.form-horizontal .form-group:last-child {margin-bottom: 0;}
```

```css
.form-horizontal .form-group:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="well">

  <div id="date_formatter_widget">

    <!-- Widget -->

    <div class="form-horizontal">

      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-9 text-right">
          <input type="text" class="form-control conversionPattern" id="pattern" placeholder="pattern here...">
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
          <input type="text" class="form-control conversionPattern" id="conversionPattern" placeholder="" readonly value="2015-05-21">
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

    <!-- /Widget -->

  </div>

</div>
```

**Preview**

[image: Preview]

Comment: Ok, but i tougth there is a solution without extending bootstrap rules.

Comment: @DanielHári Okay... Lemme check once, if the way you have written the classes are right.

Comment: @DanielHári No boss. There's no option, as you are using it inside the well, and it has already a fixed padding on all sides and form groups **will** have bottom margin always, to accommodate. Since there's no built in, form inside well, you need to override. Sorry!